# How can I setup Jenkins-x on local kubernetes cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, jenkins-x

Recently, I tried to setup Jenkins X on a kubernetes cluster. However there exists some problem during installation.

There are several options in `jx create cluster` such as aks(create with AKS), aws(create with AWS), minikube(create with Minikube) and etc.

However there is no option which create a cluster with local kubernetes cluster. I want to setup Jenkins X with my own cluster.

Can I get some advice?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you have your cluster setup such that you can run `kubectl` commands against it, you can run `jx boot` to setup your jx installation. You don't need to use `jx create cluster` as your cluster already exists.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I understand what you're saying. I just run setup with `jx boot`, however it waits for something related to ingress service. It said "No domain flag provided so using default to generate Ingress rules ... waiting for external Host on the ingress service `jxing-nginx-ingress-controller` in namespace `kube-system`". It seems like I should do something related to ingress service. Is that right?

Comment: that looks like if you wait it will set it up if I read correctly

Comment: I expected that, however it failed to find the Ingress domain. But I found some pods related to jxing-nginx-ingress-controller with `kubectl get pods -n kube-system`.

Comment: Actually when I get serive with name(jxing-nginx-ingress-controller), the service was pending, I thought boot would be go forward when I running this service properly. Am I in the right track?

Answer (score 1):

To install Jenkins X on already existing cluster, you have to use the below command:

```
jx install --provider=kubernetes --on-premise
```

Above command will install the jx on your cluster.